# Take ownership over My Sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, security, my-site

Cannot find a way to add an Administrator account (or, for example, Company Administrator group) into Site Collection Administrators list for *each* of Personal (i.e. My) Sites at SharePoint Online instance. This should be done by script ore once in the Administration portal.

Despite all tries, the only thing I've managed to do is adding such Administrator with 'Read' permissions - it is not what I want.

1. PowerShell for SharePoint Online is not powerful enough to carry this out.
2. CSOM model seems to have ability of changing the owner/permissions list for the Personal site, but it ends up with 'Access denied', because the only man who is in Site Collection Administrators list is the person who's site is (and the script should be ran under the Administrator credentials).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your MySites in a seperate web application?

Comment: Just a standard schema for SharePoint Online: team site at https://xxx.sharepoint.com and My Sites Host at https://xxx-my.sharepoint.com

Comment: this is not an answer, It´s just that they seem to have deleted the walkthrough at the link, and I cant find it googling. Does anyone still have the solution?

Answer (score 1):

There are two points at which someone can be added as a site collection admin for the user's My Site: on site creation; and later by the tenant administrator.

Under the SharePoint Online tenant admin portal, you can go to **User Profiles** -> **Setup My Sites**. From here, you can add additional owners to *new* My Sites and set the secondary owner of the site collection when it is deleted. As noted above, this would only apply the admin settings to new My Sites after the settings are applied.

Adding an additional admin after the site is created is a little trickier but can be done by the tenant administrator. (You can follow [this TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn911464.aspx) if you need a list of My Sites that are already created.) The SharePoint Online PowerShell Management suite should be good enough to handle this task.

```
$tenant = "contoso"    
$site = "user1_contoso_com"  
$user = "admin@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"  
Set-SPOUser -Site https://$tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/$site `
    -LoginName $user -IsSiteCollectionAdmin $true
```

This is based on the examples in [this TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt771884.aspx) about managing groups.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this walk-through. The difficulty you are looking at is related to the intent of MySites. MySites in this instance is a web application and that will be where you need to add the perms. You will not see your name in the site perms but you should have full access to every site.
http://blogs.syrinx.com/blogs/sharepoint/archive/2007/10/19/how-to-manage-administrator-permissions-on-my-sites.aspx

Comment: The link is dead. Can you include more information in the answer?